# How can i validate password to have multiple upper case letters

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a custom validator function which uses an RegEx to determine a match.

```
newPassword: [
          null,
          Validators.compose([
            Validators.required,
            // check whether the entered password has a number
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/\d/, {
              hasNumber: true
            }),
            // check whether the entered password has upper case letter
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]/, {
              hasCapitalCase: true
            }),
            // check whether the entered password has a lower case letter
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[a-z]/, {
              hasSmallCase: true
            }),
            // check whether the entered password has a special character
            CustomValidators.patternValidator(
              /[ !@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?]/,
              {
                hasSpecialCharacters: false
              }
            ),
            Validators.minLength(8)
          ])
        ]
```

and the function looks like this

```
export class CustomValidators {
static patternValidator(regex: RegExp, error: ValidationErrors): ValidatorFn {
return (control: AbstractControl): { [key: string]: any } => {
  if (!control.value) {
    // if control is empty return no error
    return null;
  }

  // test the value of the control against the regexp supplied
  const valid = regex.test(control.value);

  // if true, return no error (no error), else return error passed in the second parameter
  return valid ? null : error;
};
}
```

my question is how can i enhance this to for example require 2 upper Case letter as my function only checks if the upper case is present.

Comment: Fwiw, imposing password rules is a bad idea. It helps the attacker because it narrrows down the search space for a brute force attack. If you are concerned about password security require a minimum length of 16.

Comment: I am not concerned about that as the user gets an initial password and only gets the restriction on upper lower case once he logs in. Also in my case you also need a onetime password via key fob to login so a Brut force attack will have 0 chance. Also after 5 fails the source ip is blocked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a quantifier to your regex. This quantifier `{2,}` means that it has to match at least two times

```
CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]{2,}/, {
              hasCapitalCase: true
 }),
```

Comment: One more thing, how would i go about to replace the 2 with a variable like this.paswdProfile.upperCase ? Static with a nbr works but when i replace the 2 with the variable it no longer works. CustomValidators.patternValidator(/[A-Z]{ this.paswdProfile.upperCase ,}/, {